# custom BarLegend in Plot

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to put a custom bar legend beside the plots.

```
barleg= BarLegend[{Blend[{{0, Hue[0., 0.1, 1]}, {1, Hue[0., 0.8, 1]}, {1.01, 
      Hue[0.3, 0.1, 1]}, {2, Hue[0.3, 0.8, 1]}, {2.01, 
      Hue[0.7, 0.1, 1]}, {3, Hue[0.7, 0.8, 1]}}, #] &, {0, 3}}, 
 "Ticks" -> {0, 1, 2, 3}, "TickLabels" -> {"0.1", "1", "10", "100"}, 
 LegendLabel -> 
  Style[HoldForm["\[Epsilon]"], 20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
 LabelStyle -> { FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 20}, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

gives what I want to attach:

[image]

But when I put this same command in Plot function, it changes simply to red

```
Plot[{}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{Blend[{{0, Hue[0., 0.1, 1]}, {1, 
         Hue[0., 0.8, 1]}, {1.01, Hue[0.3, 0.1, 1]}, {2, 
         Hue[0.3, 0.8, 1]}, {2.01, Hue[0.7, 0.1, 1]}, {3, 
         Hue[0.7, 0.8, 1]}}, #] &, {0, 3}}, "Ticks" -> {0, 1, 2, 3}, 
    "TickLabels" -> {"0.1", "1", "10", "100"}, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     Style[HoldForm["\[Epsilon]"], 20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    LabelStyle -> { FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 20}], Right]
 ]
```

gives

[image]

How do I get the exact bar legend with the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` to `BarLegend`:

```
Plot[{}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{Blend[{{0, Hue[0., 0.1, 1]}, {1, 
         Hue[0., 0.8, 1]}, {1.01, Hue[0.3, 0.1, 1]}, {2, 
         Hue[0.3, 0.8, 1]}, {2.01, Hue[0.7, 0.1, 1]}, {3, 
         Hue[0.7, 0.8, 1]}}, #] &, {0, 3}}, "Ticks" -> {0, 1, 2, 3}, 
    "TickLabels" -> {"0.1", "1", "10", "100"}, 
    LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm["ϵ"], 20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 20}, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False], Right]]
```

[image]